# Insert closing "input" HTML element

Tags: c#

I need to insert a closing "input" element where not present in a string, in C#.

For example:

```
This is some content <input type="readonly" value="value1"> and 
there is further content. This is some additional <input type="readonly" 
value="value2"> text and then there is further text.
```

must be replaced with having closing "input" element:

```
This is some content <input type="readonly" value="value1"></input> and 
there is further content. This is some additional <input type="readonly" 
value="value2"></input> text and then there is further text.
```

Note that there would be no content between the opening and closing "input" elements, it just needs to be provided with a closing "input" element as soon as the opening "input" element ends.

Comment: `input` doesn't have a closed tag. It is just `<input type="readonly" value="value1"/>`

Comment: @Aishvarya: You don't even need `/>` on void elements. http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tags/f/html5-use-trailing-slash.htm

Comment: It is possible to have "input" with a closing "/input" tag. it is valid, and that is what I want, since during parsing, it is expecting a closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, I am sure there is more elegant way but here it is

```
static void AddClosingTag()
{
    string input = "This is some content <input type='readonly' value='value1'> and there is further content. This is some additional <input type='readonly' value='value2'> text and then there is further text.";

    int index = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        index = input.IndexOf("<input", index);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        index = input.IndexOf(">", index);
        input = input.Insert(index + 1, "</input>");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `.IndexOf("<input", index, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` to make the comparison slightly more robust?